# Kunta@icloud.com

Tags: activation-lock

My sister was updating my phone and it when to activation lock and tried to remove it but I could not and I have forgotten my iCloud
I am only having the password
So am looking forward for you to help me

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer with your question?
- It sounds like your phone is currently in the activation lock state.   
- When you say you have "forgotten your iCloud I am only having the password" do you mean you don't know the iCloud username, but you have the password?
- Can you post a photo of what your phone is currently doing?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Activation Lock for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201365), "Your Apple ID password or device passcode is required before anyone can turn off Find My, erase your device, or reactivate and use your device."  I read this to mean that if you have the iCloud account credentials OR you have the phone PIN code you should be able to unlock the Activation Lock mode.